# Cisco CML 2.0 strange ASA trunking issue

Tags: cisco, switch, firewall, cisco-nexus, cisco-nx-os

I am seeing very strange issue and now i am losing my mind so thought ask you folk. I have following two components connected point to point on Cisco CML 2.0

```
[nxos-9000v]--------------------[ASAv]
```

9000v config

```
interface Vlan10
  no shutdown
  ip address 10.10.10.2/24
!
interface Ethernet1/3
  description connected to ASA
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10
```

ASA config

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 vlan 10
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

I can't ping 10.10.10.2 from ASA

But if i configure 9000v e1/3 interface switchport and ASA side if i remove VLAN config and put direct IP on g0/0 interface then everything works. Am i missing something to configure cisco ASA vlan config?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with VLAN tags. The 9000v should be tagging and expecting VLAN tags on a trunk interface.

Comment: Check this out i post my question here - https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/i3cjez/cisco_cml_strange_issue_with_cisco_asa_trunk/

Comment: Even i configure `mac-address auto` still its not working for me.

Comment: I see the question about creating VLAN 10, and the response was `int vlan10`, but that creates the SVI, not the VLAN. You create the VLAN with the global `Vlan 10` command, then you can name the VLAN, among other VLAN configurations. Not doing that can cause strange problems.

Comment: I did created "vlan 10" and name it `FOO` then i create `int vlan10` with IP and assigned it to interface e1/3 as trunk

Comment: When you assign a trunk, it will add VLAN tags to the frames. If the other side is not expecting tags, it will drop the frames. Make sure the other side tags and expects tags, or you could make VLAN 10 the native VLAN, which will not have tags.

Comment: @RonMaupin I just created same lab on `EVE-NG` simulator and everything works in single shot without any issue. but in EVE-NG i am running ASA 9.8.1 version and on CML cisco ASA 9.12.1